# Can't use SpriteEffects to flip

Tags: c#, xna

Hey im trying to flip one of my background images so in the constructor in the background class i used SpriteEffects so on construction i could tell whether or not i wanted to flip but by doing this nothing happens.  I have tried a few things but i am stumped.

Can anyone help me with this?

BackgroundSprite

```
public class BackgroundSprite : Sprite
{

 public BackgroundSprite(string name, TextureData textureData, SpritePresentationInfo spritePresentationInfo,
   SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo,SpriteEffects spriteEffects)
    : base(name, textureData, spritePresentationInfo, spritePositionInfo)
{

}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Use this if we do not want to use the parents
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Use this if we do not want to use the parents
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
}
```

Main

```
//Get the texture to draw.
            TextureData sky3TextureData = textureManager.Get("Sky_Back");
            //How to draw the Texture
            SpritePresentationInfo sky3PresentationInfo = new SpritePresentationInfo(sky3TextureData.FULLSOURCERECTANGLE, 0.8f);
            SpritePositionInfo sky3PositionInfo = new SpritePositionInfo(new Vector2(1600, 0), sky3TextureData.Width(), sky3TextureData.Height(), 0, 1f, Vector2.Zero);
            //Add the sprite to the game.
            SpriteEffects flip = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally;
            this.backgroundSprite = new BackgroundSprite("Sky_Back", sky3TextureData, sky3PresentationInfo, sky3PositionInfo, flip);
            spriteManager.Add(backgroundSprite);
```

Comment: How do you actually draw the sprite? This is a 3D application, right?

Comment: No 2d i draw the sprite in a class called Sprite public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            SpriteManager.GAME.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(textureData.TEXTURE,
                spritePositionInfo.MOVE, 
                spritePresentationInfo.SOURCERECTANGLE,
                spritePresentationInfo.COLOR,
                MathHelper.ToRadians(spritePositionInfo.ROTATIONINDEGREES),
                spritePositionInfo.ORIGIN,
                spritePositionInfo.SCALE,
                spritePresentationInfo.SPRITEEFFECTS,
                spritePresentationInfo.LAYERDEPTH);
        }

Comment: BackgroundSprite Extends this.

Comment: When you debug your drawing code, are the sprite effects set correctly?

Comment: yep, i have the flip working for the player sprite correctly the same way

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
public BackgroundSprite(string name, TextureData textureData, SpritePresentationInfo       spritePresentationInfo,
   SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo,SpriteEffects spriteEffects)
    : base(name, textureData, spritePresentationInfo, spritePositionInfo)
{

}
```

You send BackgroundSprite a SpriteEffects, but SpriteEffects is not sent or used anywhere else. It seems SpriteEffects must be added to the Base constructor.

```
public BackgroundSprite(string name, TextureData textureData, SpritePresentationInfo       spritePresentationInfo,
   SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo,SpriteEffects spriteEffects)
    : base(name, textureData, spritePresentationInfo, spritePositionInfo, spriteEffects)
{

}
```

Comment: But this is the only class i want to use spriteEffects in if i do that i have to put it in sprite and its other sub classes...